# PYTHON: How to extract multiple regex patterns from list of text files and store as data frame?

Tags: python, regex, function, pandas, text

I have a list of .txt files Each txt file contains multiple newspaper articles. On average, each file contains about 400 articles.

I want to define a function that maps over the list, extracting 1) publication date and 2) body text from each file, and returns a pandas data frame of date and text.

I have regex patterns that will match the relevant strings (they've worked for the same procedure in R), but I haven't been able to define a function that works.

Thanks in advance for the help with this beginner question!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know how to define a function:

```py
import re


def split_date_body(data):
    p = re.compile(r'(Date),\s*(Body.*)')
    Date, Body = p.findall(data)[0]
    return Date, Body

data = 'Date, Body xxxx'
print(split_date_body(data))
```

change `r'(Date),\s*(Body.*)'` to your regex

if you don't know how to parse file with multiple lines:

```py
with open(your_file, 'r') as f:
    datas = f.readlines()

for data in datas:
    result = split_date_body(data)
```